# Improving the performance of interpolating between two arrays

Tags: python, performance, array

**The Problem**

I am currently writing a script that converts images into numerical array representation and then calculates "in-between" images based on linear interpolation between the start and end array.

My code does exactly what I want but goes over many nested loops which strikes me as something that will lead to very high computation times for many interpolation steps or big images.

**The Code**

The code is in python

```py
import numpy as np

# Helper function that calculates the interpolation between two points
def interpolate_points(p1, p2, n_steps=3):
    # interpolate ratios between the points
    ratios = np.linspace(0, 1, num=n_steps)
    # linear interpolate vectors
    vectors = list()
    for ratio in ratios:
        v = (1.0 - ratio) * p1 + ratio * p2
        vectors.append(v)
    return np.asarray(vectors)

# final function that interpolates arrays
def interpolate_arrays(start_array,end_array,n_steps=10):
    n = 0
    array_interpolation = []
    while n < n_steps:
        i = 0
        x = []
        while i < len(start_array):
            e = interpolate_points(start_array[i],end_array[i],n_steps)[n]
            x.append(e)
            i += 1
        array_interpolation += [x]
        n += 1
    return array_interpolation
```

This results in:

```py
#Test
X1 = [1,1]
X2 = [3,3]

interpolate_arrays(X1,X2,n_steps=3)
#[[1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some easy wins here. Your `interpolate_points` doesn't need a loop:

```
def interpolate_points(p1, p2, n_steps=3):
    """Helper function that calculates the interpolation between two points"""
    # interpolate ratios between the points
    ratios = np.linspace(0, 1, num=n_steps)
    # linear interpolate vectors
    vectors = (1.0 - ratios) * p1 + ratios * p2
    return vectors
```

Also, even without further vectorization, you should be making use of `range` in your main function:

```
def interpolate_arrays(start_array, end_array, n_steps=10):
    """final function that interpolates arrays"""
    array_interpolation = []
    for n in range(n_steps):
        x = []
        for i in range(len(start_array)):
            e = interpolate_points(start_array[i], end_array[i], n_steps)[n]
            x.append(e)
        array_interpolation += [x]
    return array_interpolation
```

However, all of that can be replaced with a call to `interp1d`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


def interpolate_arrays(bounds, n_steps=10):
    """final function that interpolates arrays"""
    bounds = np.array(bounds)

    fun = interp1d(
        x=[0, 1],
        y=bounds.T,
    )
    y = fun(np.linspace(0, 1, n_steps))

    return y


def test():
    X1 = [1.5, 1]
    X2 = [5.5, 3]

    y = interpolate_arrays([X1, X2], n_steps=3)
    assert y.T.tolist() == [[1.5, 1.0], [3.5, 2.0], [5.5, 3.0]]
```

Even easier:

```
def interpolate_arrays(X1, X2, n_steps=10):
    """final function that interpolates arrays"""
    return np.linspace(X1, X2, n_steps)


def test():
    X1 = [1.5, 1]
    X2 = [5.5, 3]

    y = interpolate_arrays(X1, X2, n_steps=3)
    assert y.tolist() == [[1.5, 1.0], [3.5, 2.0], [5.5, 3.0]]
```

Notes:

- If you use `interp1d`, it would be better if your inputs and outputs are both two-dimensional `np.ndarray`; in their current form they need a transposition
- Write some unit tests such as the one shown, although it would be a better idea to call `isclose` since this is floating-point math
- If you want, it is trivial to make this extrapolate as well as interpolate

Basically: if there is a math thing in your head, before even thinking about what it would take to implement it yourself, do a search through `scipy`/`numpy` to see if it has already been done for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is answer is both a helpful guide for improvements as well as a good "SO just give me the final code"-style answer.